# Lein uberjar fails on simple '-main' usage, but perhaps I don't understand all it's doing?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I've created a simple example using:

```
%> lein new lein-check
```

I've only modified the code so that it now has a 'main':

```
(defproject lein-check "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :main "lein-check.core"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]])

(ns lein-check.core
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

But the first time I run `lein uberjar` even after a `clean` I get this:

```
Compiling lein-check.core
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
     java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol
        at clojure.core$find_ns.invoke(core.clj:3659)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5228)
        at clojure.core$compile$fn__4895.invoke(core.clj:5426)
        at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5425)
        at user$eval7.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6501)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6477)
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2797)
        at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:297)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:316)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:349)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
```

Running a follow up `uberjar` though successfully creates the jars:

```
Created ....\lein-check-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including lein-check-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including clojure-1.4.0.jar
Created ....\lein-check-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

Is uberjar sometimes running the main after a completion?  Is it supposed to do that?  I'm not quite sure if this is a user error, a `lein` bug or a clojure bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
 :main "lein-check.core"
```

It should be

```
 :main lein-check.core
```

You're using a string instead of a symbol.

Comment: Right -- same as my answer I suppose except I have a quoted 'symbol for the :main, and they both seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Well it turns out that the [Lein Sample Project](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L113) show the `:main` as a symbol and not a string.  Once this was updated then running `lein uberjar` works as expected.

This line in particular:

`:main "lein-check.core"`

changed to:

`:main 'lein-check.core`